# How to convert row names of table into a vector

Tags: r

I have returned stats on my data using the table command as such:

```
subject<-c(4,4,2,2,3,3)
correct<-c(0,1,1,1,0,0)
test<-data.frame(subject,correct)
freq_test<-head(table(test$subject,test$correct))
```

This returns a table which looks like this

```
    0 1

  2 0 2

  3 2 0

  4 1 1
```

That's great, but the problem is that I would like, the first column to be a vector rather than row.names (so that I can code it properly as "subject").
Is there a way to get this column to act in this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just make a new data frame with the row names of `freq_test` as the first column:

```
> df<-data.frame(as.numeric(rownames(freq_test)),freq_test)
> colnames(df)[1]="subject"
> df
  subject X0 X1
2       2  0  2
3       3  2  0
4       4  1  1
>
```

Of course, you can rename `X0` and `X1` to whatever you want by editing `colnames(df)` as above.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the check mark below the upvote/downvote totals for my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data in "long" format (useful for some models and plotting, and especially when your tables are more complicated), the table method for the generic function `as.data.frame` will take care of this for you:

```
> as.data.frame(table(test))
  subject correct Freq
1       2       0    0
2       3       0    2
3       4       0    1
4       2       1    2
5       3       1    0
6       4       1    1
```

Comment: useful, but not quite what I need as the summarised data was the point of getting the table().

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have used the standard method of construction of a data.frame, which is with name=values pairs:

```
test <- data.frame( subject=subject, correct=correct)
```

The first `subject` will be interpreted as a name to be quoted and the second `subject` will be *interpreted* .... i.e, the enclosing environments will be searched for an object named `subject` and its value will be assigned to the "subject" column of "test".

Comment: However, I don't think this helps when the head(table(test)) is used as this is when the row.names are created